# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null delegate icon argument

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have created Java project in Eclipse. First login page and after login page  Main Frame is there which contain `JMenubar`...after clicking `JMenuItem` another `JInternalFrame` open. It works well in Eclipse...but if I tried to open through jar only login page open and not move on another frame...so tried on cmd 
`java -jar C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\26thJuly.jar`   so it gives error:-

```
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null delegate icon argument
        at javax.swing.plaf.IconUIResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme$IFIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme$4.createValue(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getIcon(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getIcon(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalInternalFrameTitlePane.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.installTitlePane(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalInternalFrameTitlePane.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalInternalFrameUI.createNorthPane(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI.installComponents(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalInternalFrameUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JInternalFrame.setUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JInternalFrame.updateUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JInternalFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JInternalFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at stock.<init>(stock.java:114)
        at New_Second.<init>(New_Second.java:58)
        at Hlogin$2.actionPerformed(Hlogin.java:97)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Use an execution environment JRE  JavaSE-1.8

Comment: Do you extend the Ocean theme with some custom icons? If yes, probably the images are missing in the JAR file.

Comment: Posting the relevant source code (`stock.<init>(stock.java:114), New_Second.<init>(New_Second.java:58), Hlogin$2.actionPerformed(Hlogin.java:97)`) would be helpful.

Comment: @howlger...not using Ocean theme at all...even I saw it first time on cmd

Comment: @Njol...on stock frame 114 line about constructor...public  stock() {.....On new_Second frame line 58 contain, stock stock=new stock();   and Hlogin contain,    New_Second frame1 = new New_Second();
   frame1.setVisible(true);

Comment: here New_Second is JFrame and stock is a JInternalFrame...If I commented stock then got same error but on another internalFrame....

Comment: Do you use the same JRE in Eclipse and on CMD? How does the classpath look like in Eclipse? Is *stock* or *New_Second* be serialized?

Comment: Yes, same JRE...classpath looks like HITECH_1/src/stock.java...and stock or New_Second not serialized

Comment: Is anyone having idea about this issue ?... Not resolved yet